# How does one create a Terminal I/O connection to a Telit BLE module?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth

I'm writing a progressive web app for an android tablet which should be able to read and write to a device with an embedded Telit BLE module via a BLE connection.

I am able to open a BLE connection and discover services and characteristics.  I am unable to establish a connection over BLE using Telit's Terminal I/O (TIO) protocol.

My remote (server) device is a Falcom Fox3 tracker unit.  A notification event can be read from the Fox3 serial port when a connection is established.  This has been successfully tested by connecting to the Fox3 using Telit's android terminal app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telit.tiosample

I have put together a short function which should connect via BLE, establish a TIO connection and request UART credits before listening for incoming data from the server.

I have based my code on a simple script from Smashing Magazine :
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/introduction-to-webbluetooth/

The process of initiating the TIO connection follows is that given in Telit's Terminal I/O Profile Client Implementation Guide .

> the Terminal I/O connection setup consists of the following steps:
>
> - The Terminal I/O client scans for Bluetooth Low Energy devices advertising the Terminal I/O service.
> - The Terminal I/O client establishes a Bluetooth Low Energy GATT connection to a detected Terminal I/O server.
> - The Terminal I/O client performs a service discovery on the Terminal I/O server.
> - For the retrieved Terminal I/O service, the Terminal I/O client performs a characteristics discovery.
> - The Terminal I/O client subscribes to indications of the UART credits TX characteristic (see 7.4).
> - The Terminal I/O client subscribes to notifications of the UART data TX characteristic (see 7.2).
> - The Terminal I/O client transmits initial UART credits to the server (see 7.5).
> - Once the Terminal I/O client has received the response for the transmitted UART credits, the Terminal I/O connection is considered established and indications for the UART credits TX characteristic and notifications for the UART data characteristic shall be expected at any time.
>
> The order of the connection setup sequence is mandatory.

My code is as follows, where log is a function which outputs to the screen.

```
const SERVICE_UUID         = "0000fefb-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
const UART_RX_UUID         = "00000001-0000-1000-8000-008025000000";
const UART_TX_UUID         = "00000002-0000-1000-8000-008025000000";
const UART_RX_CREDITS_UUID = "00000003-0000-1000-8000-008025000000";
const UART_TX_CREDITS_UUID = "00000004-0000-1000-8000-008025000000";

async function tio_connect() {
  let device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ namePrefix: 'FOX' }],
  optionalServices: [SERVICE_UUID]
  });
  log(" - Connecting<br>");
  let server = await device.gatt.connect();
  log(" - Getting Primary Service<br>");
  let service = await server.getPrimaryService(SERVICE_UUID);
  log(" - Subscribing to tx credits<br>");
  let tx_credits = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_TX_CREDITS_UUID);
  log(" - Subscribing to tx data<br>");    
  let tx_data = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_TX_UUID);
  log(" - Requesting credits<br>");   
  tx_credits.writeValue(new Uint8Array([255]));
  log(" - Starting listener<br>");   
  tx_data.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', e => {log (e.value)});
  tx_data.startNotifications();
}
```

This runs without error and appears to establish a bluetooth connection on my client android device.  I expect the server to respond to the connection, trigger an event and report it back.  No such connection event occurs.

I am new to web bluetooth and a little rusty with JavaScript, so unsure whether I am using the correct calls - particularly for 'subscribing'.  If anyone could clarify what subscribing involves in this context it would certainly help my understanding.

**Edit:
I was able to get the connection running once I figured out how the Terminal I/O connection instructions translate to JS.**

I performed these steps like this:
"For the retrieved Terminal I/O service, the Terminal I/O client performs a characteristics discovery."

```
let tx_credits = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_TX_CREDITS_UUID)
let tx_data = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_TX_UUID)
let rx_credits = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_RX_CREDITS_UUID)
let rx_data = await service.getCharacteristic(UART_RX_UUID)
```

"The Terminal I/O client subscribes to indications of the UART credits TX characteristic (see 7.4)."

```
await tx_credits.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', e => {log ("<br>tx_credits: " + e.value)});
await tx_credits.startNotifications();
```

"The Terminal I/O client subscribes to notifications of the UART data TX characteristic (see 7.2)."

```
await tx_data.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', e => {
  for (i=1;tx_data.value.getUint8(i);i++){
    log(String.fromCharCode(tx_data.value.getUint8(i)))
  }    
}
await tx_data.startNotifications();
```

"The Terminal I/O client transmits initial UART credits to the server (see 7.5)."

```
let rx_credit_level = await rx_credits.writeValue(new Uint8Array([255]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to await `writeValue` and `startNotifications`.

```js
...
log(" - Requesting credits<br>");   
await tx_credits.writeValue(new Uint8Array([255]));
log(" - Starting listener<br>");   
tx_data.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', e => {log (e.value)});
await tx_data.startNotifications();
```

Comment: That certainly helped.  The problem really rested on getting all the right steps done in the right order - and I needed to add some extra steps before my device registered a connection.